# User Authentication through REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, session, authentication, polymer-1.0

I have been researching this topic for some time but I am unable to really find any useful information, so I thought that would ask the question here.

I have a REST API, this is already built, already deployed, and I am not able to edit. I am trying to utilize this REST API in order to build a web app (using Polymer.) The issue that I cannot seem to tackle is user authentication.

The REST API that is used handles all of the authentication functions for me. All I need to do is send the POST request with a base64 encoded username and password as a header option and the server does the rest (simple enough).

After the user is authenticated the response creates a cookie on the client with a JSESSIONID, this is what the server uses to authenticate the user for the following requests until the session limit is reached so that the encoded header option doesn't need to be sent with following requests.

Once the session expires on the server, requests will return 400 errors that simply say require user name and password.

My question is what is the best way of handling this in a JavaScript based client? I want to be able to handle the expiration gracefully however there are really no methods (that I can think of as to how to handle this session.)

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use jwt token based authentication?

Comment: base64 isn't secure, so be carefull

Answer (score 0):

Have a dummy servlet, which will just receive the requests and does nothing. Trigger Ajax calls on click on the buttons or on some UI activity of the user to this dummy servlet. The reason behind these Ajax calls is to just extend the session.

Whenever your session expires, you will get erroneous response which will have 401(Unauthorized) status code. As soon as you get 401 status code, redirect to the login page.

In case of single page application, this approach is preferable as all the resources loaded once in the browser.
I think this will suffice your concern.